# how to stream (read & write) a remote file in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, streaming

I have a big file in server and I would like to 
make a react native app to write/read the file remotely by streaming.

In Java there is something like InputStream and OutputStream.

is there any similar api in react native/JS ?

Comment: Check this package:
https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob

Comment: @sia can this package communicate to a java endpoint, which use inputstream to read data?

Comment: closest I found https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/advanced/streams/how-to-use-fs-create-read-stream/